# Why does reference update automatically?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, comparator, treemap

I have this code. It should order the map by the integer value.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(map);
        TreeMap<String,Integer> sorted_map = new TreeMap<>(bvc);

        map.put("A",5);
        map.put("B",4);
        map.put("C",4);
        map.put("D",2);

        System.out.println("unsorted map: "+map);

        sorted_map.putAll(map);

        System.out.println("results: "+sorted_map);


    }
}

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Integer> base;
    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Integer> base) {
        this.base = base;
        System.out.println("Map: " + base);
    }

    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And it works fine.
But first as parameter for the ValueComparator instance I give the constructor an empty hashmap. And this empty map is saved in *base*. Then I create the treemap with the comparator. Then I put the stuff in the map and it automatically updates the reference in the ValueComparator called *base*. Why does the map passed to the ValueComparator update automatically? Actually the *base* variable should be still an empty map. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the base variable should be still an empty map. Isn't it?

No, the moment you call `ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(map);`

both map and basemap are referring to the same object, because of `this.base = base;`

And above justifies why "Then I put the stuff in the map and it automatically updates the reference in the ValueComparator called base" happens.

Answer (score 2):

In java all variables are passed by value (a copy of the reference), so you will have 2 variables that refer to the same object.. so when you mutate that object it's reflect in the other one.

For example :

```
public class Test{

public static void main(String args []){
   Test test = new Test();
   Collection<String> collection = new LinkedList<>();
   collection.add("a");
   collection.add("b");
   someMethod(collection);
   System.out.println(collection); // will print [a,b];
   modifyCollection(collection);
   System.out.println(collection); // will print [a,b,c];
}

public void modifyCollection(Collection collection){
    collection.add("c");
}

public void someMethod(Collection collection){
    collection = new ArrayList();
    collection.add("nasda");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, references to classes are pass-by-value. So when you pass your empty `HashMap` to the `ValueComparator`, you are actually storing a reference to it in `bvc`. Then, when you modify the `HashMap`, `bvc.base`, being a reference to it, is "updated automatically."

EDIT: Took into account Jon Skeet's reply.

Comment: No, Java is pass by value - but the *reference* is passed by value. Calling it pass by reference is confusing for those who understand true pass by reference.

Comment: Is that always the case? So could I pass a string to a constructor, then change the string, and then call some method in the constructed class which outputs the string. Would it be the new string?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock String is immutable. But if you reassign the string in the method, return, and sys.out it from your caller, you'll have the same value as before you called the method. Which makes the fact that java is pass by value very clear.

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock in principle, yes. However there are no methods on a String in Java that can change the string - it is immutable

Comment: So summarized When I save an object in a variable and then pass this variable to a constructor or method - then I change the value of the original variable and the passed object will be changed too?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock i give you an example in my answer, hope it helps to understand

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock Nomenclature is particularly important here. When you pass a reference variable to a method and within that method call methods or access fields, you're accessing them on the same referenced object.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the map passed to the ValueComparator update automatically?

When you pass an `object` variable into a method, you pass a copy of the `reference variable`. Hence both the caller and the called method will now have identical copy of the reference and thus both will refer to same exact `object` on the heap. That's why changes made on the object by one variable is seen by the other variable.
That's Why the `map` passed to the `ValueComparator` update automatically when you put the stuff in the `map`.